# Some mod_rewrite syntax clarification

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

We inherited some code recently and I'm reviewing the .htaccess file of one of the sites. I understand what the end result of most of the rewrite rule sets are, I'm just unsure of some of the syntax. Background info: CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4, running the Concrete5 CMS.

Example 1:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I understand that %{HTTPS} is one of the special variables provided by mod_rewrite that evaluates to either `on` or `off`. In a previous rule, I see `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on` which makes more sense and goes along with what the documentation shows [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). So in the above example, I have the following questions:

1. What is the trailing "s" for in %{HTTPS}s
2. Why does the pattern use ^on instead of =on. Is this valid?
3. I understand that anything in parenthesis can be back referenced with %1, but it's placement here doesn't really make sense to me. If %{HTTPS} is going to evaluate to `on` or `off`, then placing (s)| in Pattern is going to make it never match the condition, right? And what's the PIPE for?

Example 2:

```
#redirect calls to index.php without get parameters to non-www
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

I'm not quite understanding the second RewriteCond.

4. What is the `\s` doing at the end of index.php?

Example 3:

Lastly, we have

```
#Standard C5 pretty urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

In the RewriteRule, the pattern is `.` which in regex means "any character".

5. Is this rule saying "If the above conditions are met, replace any character with index.php"? What is this rule doing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please ignore this answer, it is wrong in many ways.

Example 1:

This rule is for forwarding non-HTTP connections to HTTPS connections. So:

1. The trailing s is for SSL.
2. `^on` is used to check "if HTTP is NOT active". `^` means negative match.
3. The references with `%` sign refer to `RewriteCond` regular expressions. In this case, `%1` refers to the `(s)` capture group, and therefore `%1` is `s` when HTTP is not active.

The way this `RewriteRule` has been written is a bit over-complicated, I think there could have been a simpler way to implement it. However, it does what it is designed to do.

Example 2:

4. The `\s` matches white space. So, this RewriteRule matches `/index.php`, that is, a space after `.php`. I think that the second `RewriteCond` makes this rule not work at all, unless some part of the website software generates incorrect URLs.

Example 3:

5. It means, "If the above conditions are met, replace any string in the URL with index.php". The `.` simply matches any string, and `index.php` is the replacement used. The match criteria in this `RewriteRule` does not need to be any more specific, since any non-existing URL is sent to `index.php`.

Comment: #1 The trailing "s" is so the "s" can be captured in the CondPattern. #2 `^` is the start of string anchor (not a "negative match"). #3 The pipe would seem to be redundant, since the _TestString_ could never be empty (because of the trailing "s"). #4 The `\s` is required in order to only match index.php at the end of the URL-path. (This is checking against `THE_REQUEST`, not `REQUEST_URI`) It prevents URLs with additional path information or query strings from being rewritten (the former would then be lost in the rewrite).

Comment: #5 The `.` matches any URL, except for the document root (when used in a `.htaccess` context). Note that the `RewriteRule` is processed first (before the RewriteCond directives that precede it). So, this ensures that all URLs, except for the document root are processed (probably avoiding a rewrite loop since mod_dir will automatically request the `DirectoryIndex` in this case).

Comment: This answer gets just about *everything* wrong!